# Is this proof of the Pythagorean theorem known?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry, triangles, alternative-proof, plane-geometry

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ be a right-triangle with $\angle{ACB}=90^\circ$. I'll be using standard notations: $a$, $b$, $c$, for the side length, $s$ for the semiperimeter, $\Delta$ for the area and r for the inradius. Then, by Poncelet theorem, $a+b=c+2r$. Squaring both sides, $a^2+2ab+b^2=c^2+4cr+4r^2$. Moreover,
$\Delta=rs$ (known) implies $2ab=4r(c+r)$. Hence $a^2+b^2=c^2$.

Is this derivation of the Pythagorean theorem known?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1853695/new-proof-of-pythagorean-theorem-using-inscribed-circle) or  [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/), particularly proof $42$ though others are similar.

Comment: I see the proof 42 is the closest to my proof, but the route I took is different.

Comment: Another similar approach is proof Forty-Eight at the bottom of page 75 of https://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/Euclid/java/html/L.pdf (p37 of pdf) which starts $h+2r=a+b$ and $h^2+4hr+4r^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ though it is a little slower to show $4r(h+r)=2ab$.  Several variants are also menaitoned

Comment: Thank you very much, Henry!

Comment: @Henry linked to the 1927 version of Loomis' *The Pythagorean Proposition*. The 1968 re-issue of the 1940 update is available [here (PDF link via ed.gov)](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED037335.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, Blue! Very helpful.

Comment: @Blue so in your pdf of the 1968 edition, that would be proof Eighty Six at the bottom of page 78 (96 of the pdf)